# Как использовать таймер в Rust

Tags: rust, таймер

Здравствуйте возник один вопрос. Как в Rust возможность использовать Таймер. Я хочу сделать программу с таймером, по истечению определенного времени программа закрывается. Подскажите как использовать таймер в Rust пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку [`chrono`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/chrono/):

Добавьте в файл `Cargo.toml` проекта зависимость `chrono`:

```
chrono = "0.4"
```

И, например, если нужно чтобы программа работала 5 секунд, пишем:

```rust
use chrono::{Local, Duration};

fn main() {
    let seconds = Duration::seconds(5);  // Сколько вам нужно секунд.

    let start = Local::now();
    loop {
        // Делаем что-то.

        if Local::now() - start >= seconds {  // Время прошло.
            return;  // Выходим.
        }
    }
}
```

*PS: этот код написан на основе [кода](https://github.com/rust-in-action/code/blob/1st-edition/ch9/ch9-clock0/src/main.rs) из книги ["Rust в действии"](https://www.manning.com/books/rust-in-action?a_aid=rust&a_bid=0367c58f&chan=source_code).*

---

А можно [`std::time`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/index.html) (спасибо @andreymal):

```rust
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

fn main() {
    let seconds = Duration::from_secs(5);  // Сколько вам нужно секунд.

    let start = Instant::now();
    loop {
        // Делаем что-то.

        if Instant::now() - start >= seconds {  // Время прошло.
            return;  // Выходим.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, а почему бы не взять [std::time](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/index.html)? Там же вроде есть всё то же самое